# Randomize classes TestNG xml

Tags: testng, testng.xml

How i can randomize my many classes in test the xml in the following example?

```
<test name="ChromeBrowserTest" verbose="2">
<parameter name="browser" value="GoogleChrome"/>
<classes>
<class name="a"/>
<class name="b"/>
<class name="c"/>
<class name="d"/>
</classes>
</test>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to randomize?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I want in the first run it do before class a then class b then... In the second class c then class a then class d... and so on. different run launch the class in different ways

Comment: You want to run the tests in different order each time?

Comment: @AlexeyR. for each class I run the tests in different order using @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class)
but when i put the classes to be launched in the xml file testNG launch the classes in the order a -> b -> c -> d

Comment: @AlexeyR.so, do you have any idea?